# How to get actual parameter by formal parameter in UglifyJS's AST?

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

Given the code:

```
(function(fn){ define(fn); })(function() { return 0; });
```

I've got the `AST_SymbolRef` of `fn` by a tree walker, how can I get the `AST_Function` of `function() { return 0; }` by that reference?